# Firebase Authentication - onAuthStateChanged doesn't get called when User get's logged out (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

Lately i started working with Firebase for a university project, now I played around with the Authentication module. I've built a Login Page with Bootstrap, where the User can sign in and also create an account. (index.html) From this Login page the user should be directed to the usermanagement.html, which is something like a main page. The problem i have is, that the onAuthStateChanged() function doesn't get called when the user is signing in. I then want the window direct to the usermanagement and the other way around.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <title>FireBase</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container w-50">
      <h1 class="display-4"><i class="mdi mdi-glass-mug-variant mdi-" aria-hidden="true"></i> FireBase</h1>
      <p class="lead">Welcome to the exclusive Club! Please login and enjoy your stay!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container w-50">
    <form id="login-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">E-Mail</label>
        <input id="txtEmail" class="form-control" type="text" name="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="txtPassword" class="form-control" type="password" name="">
      </div>
      <a id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3" href="#usermanagement.html" role="button">Login</a>
      <a id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3" href="#usermanagement.html" role="button">Create Account</a>
      <a id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3" href="#usermanagement.html" role="button">Logout</a>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

   <!-- Own script -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

usermanagement.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <title>FireBase</title>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23bpce-5s8I) -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
      <i class="mdi mdi-glass-mug-variant mdi-" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      FireBase
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Benutzer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Planung</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <a id="btnLogout" class="btn btn-outline-danger mb-2" role="button">Logout</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Container -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

      </div>
      <div class="col">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>


    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
(() => { 
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDq34a0xF5q_aIuCuFsPSJmDqyRZYtC2_E",
    authDomain: "webengineeringproject-c5fc7.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://webengineeringproject-c5fc7.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "webengineeringproject-c5fc7",
    storageBucket: "webengineeringproject-c5fc7.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "290017335954",
    appId: "1:290017335954:web:951bd3f4baeaf89075244b",
    measurementId: "G-PCTZ4HQV52"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  // Set variable for Database
  var db = firebase.firestore();

  //get all UI Elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword");
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById("btnSignUp");
  const btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");
  const btnLogout = document.getElementById("btnLogout");

//Process entered login-data
  btnLogin.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let email = txtEmail.value;
    let password = txtPassword.value;

    const auth = firebase.auth();

    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    promise
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        //TODO: Error Message, login Failed
    });
  });

  btnSignUp.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let email = txtEmail.value;
    let password = txtPassword.value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((error) => {
      // TODO: Error Message if new Account couldn't be created
    });
  });

  btnLogout.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Logout!")
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)
  });

  //Code runs when User state changes
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      if(window.location.pathname == "/index.html") {
        window.location.href = "usermanagement.html";
      }
    } else if(window.location.pathname == "/usermanagement") {
      window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Your title says the `onAuthStateChanged` handler doesn't get called when the user signs **out**, while in the question itself you say it doesn't get called when the user signs **in**. Which one is it?

Comment: Also note that you're missing `.html` in here: `if *window.location.pathname == "/usermanagement")`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my little mistakes. It's all still work in progress. It doesn't work both ways. I mainly testing if it works wenn the User tries to login, because, without login, i can't really test the logout funktionality. I hope its the same problem both ways.

Comment: I'm still not sure what works and doesn't. If you put a breakpoint on `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(` and run the app in a debugger, does it trigger that breakpoint? If so, what if you also put a breakpoint on `if (user) {`? Does it reach that? If so what is the value of `user`?

Comment: Thank you for your help, while trying to see what's happening when I set a breakpoint at the function I've noticed that the whole script wasn't running because I've removed the document eventlistener while testing some other things. Now I've added the eventlistener and everything works fine.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. For future questions please follow the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At worst it will make it easier for us to help you, but it's also quite common for folks to find the solution to their own problem while following the guidelines in that page.